# How to get perticular values from JSON data?

Tags: jquery, json, javascript-objects

This is may JSON Data and I want to get  site name only

```
var mydata=<%- JSON.stringify(mydata)%>;
```

[
  {"site_name":"JaiKruti","site_id":1,"site_code" :"Jaikruti",";area_name":"Bandra","customer_id"

:6,"customer_name":"CSS","site_pincode"

:"400005","site_latitude":"","site_longitude"

:"","}
]

I used
    site_name=mydata.site_name;
But its showing undefined

Comment: you have to parse it not stringify to fetch properties

Comment: `JSON.parse(mydata)` then access property

Comment: if i use JSON.parse(mydata) Its showing Error page

Comment: what error it is showing

Comment: are you using jquery? then you can `$.parseJSON(data):`

Answer (score 0):

To create a json string from an object `JSON.stringify()`

To create an object from a json string `JSON.parse()`

In your case you need to use the second function.

```
var myData = JSON.parse(myData);
console.log(myData.site_name)
```